# Makefile C command line argument

Tags: c, makefile, command-line-arguments

To run my program the unix command line is "p2 -s input.txt"

Normally (without a makefile) to check that the flag == -s I would have my unix input be - a.out -s input.txt, and my main.c would be:

```
int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    if(argv[1] == "-s")
    {
        printf("The flag is -s\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The flag is not -s");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I code this with a makefile, should I change how I check the flag? Or do I need to change the parameters of the main.c? My makefile is:

```
all: p2
p2: main.o functions.o
    gcc -o p2 main.o functions.o
main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c
functions.o: functions.c
    gcc -c functions.c
clean:
    rm -f *.o core
```

Comment: I guess you should use `strcmp(argv[1], "-s") == 0` instead of `argv[1] == "-s"`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why would the makefile affect how you write the code for parsing the program's command line? The makefile helps you build the program. Then you run the program exactly as you normally would.

Comment: Thank you @mikeCAT. I thought I tried that before and I thought it gave me an error of comparing a pointer and an integer. Thank you I appreciate the help!

Comment: @kaylum I kept getting errors of comparing a pointer and an integer and I thought it would have a problem with the makefile because I am still very new to makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test

```
if(argv[1] == "-s")
```

does not work in C like it looks.  C++ is often overloaded for this to work intuitively, but what C does is:

1. compare for equality the value of `argv[1]` to the value of `"-s"`
2. The value of the first is some address near the top of stack (one entry from the beginning of wherever `argv[]` is located, which is set up by the C runtime library or the operating system).
3. The value of the second is a pointer to a string constant.
4. The addresses are not equal, so the `if` expression evaluates to 0 (zero).
5. So the `else` branch is taken.

Use the string.h function `strcmp()` to compare strings at given addresses.  In C, a string is a sequence of characters terminated by ascii NUL.

Also, note that your definition of `main()` is flawed, as noted by [MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35643520/198536).

Comment: Look at the code closely. The second argument is `char argv[]`, not `char *argv[]`. Thus `argv[1]` is not an address.

Comment: @MikeCAT:  Yikes!  I missed that.  I would have expected most compilers to squawk about it too with an implied prototype for `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should change how you check the flag regardless of whether you use `Makefile`, because it is not the standard and having no chance to success way to compare strings in C.

You should use `strcmp()` to compare strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* correct the type of second argument to the standard one, or strcmp() won't work */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(strcmp(argv[1] "-s") == 0)
    {
        printf("The flag is -s\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The flag is not -s");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Altenatively, you can compare each characters manually because the flag string is short.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* correct the type of second argument to the standard one, or strcmp() won't work */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] == 's' && argv[1][2] == '\0')
    {
        printf("The flag is -s\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The flag is not -s");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing of command line options is a fairly well-solved issue - you could use `getopt()` or libpopt (https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Popt). @MikeCAT has explained the other issues you had with string comparison.